# Accessing JS object with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm having trouble accessing a particular object using a variable in javascript. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
global_grouplist = getTenantGroupList();
console.log(global_grouplist)
var currentgroup = getSelectedGroupName();
console.log(currentgroup)
console.log(global_grouplist.currentgroup);
```

'global_grouplist' returns a large array of objects, and I want to get a particular value from there. If I take the value that currentgroup will equal, and run it like this:

```
console.log(global_grouplist.actualvalue)
```

It gives me what I want. However, when I do this.

```
var currentgroup = actualvalue
console.log(global_grouplist.currentgroup)
```

This is the getTenantGroupList() function:

```
function getTenantGroupList(){
    return jQuery.parseJSON($.ajax({
            url: 'tenantgrouplist.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false
    }).responseText);
}
```

And here is the getSelectedGroupName function:

```
function getSelectedGroupName(){
        var retval = null;
        $('#grouplist li a').each(function(){
            if($(this).parent().hasClass('group-selected'))
                retval=$(this).html();
        });
        return retval;
    }
```

It does not work. Is there something fundamental I'm missing here? If you need more information, please let me know!

Comment: By the way if you are receiving JSON from the server (with the good header) you should not have to parse it, the response should come as an Javascript object already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the properties in this manner you need to use array notation. Try this:

```
var currentgroup = getSelectedGroupName(); // Returns a string like: 'actualvalue';
console.log(global_grouplist[currentgroup])
```

Answer (score 2):

With this row

```
var currentgroup = actualvalue
```

you are giving the current value of `actualvalue` to `currentgroup` and do not make both elements point towards the same property!

If you want to use `currentgroup` as a placeholder for a variable, you should use this instead:

```
var currentgroup = 'actualvalue';
console.log(global_grouplist[currentgroup]);
```

That way you assign the name of the desired property as a string to `currentgroup` and use the bracket notation to access the respective property of your object.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the explanation as well, it is very helpful. However, if I'm using a function for actual value (var currentgroup = functionGettingActualValue() ) -- how does that change things?

Comment: @streetlight It doesn't change anything as long as the function returns the property identifier as a string.

Comment: Nevermind -- I just used your notation and realized I had been doing it wrong. Thank you so much for your patience and help!